# proof verification for $A_n\uparrow A \implies A-A_n\downarrow \emptyset$

Tags: proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

For the sequence of sets $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$I have that $A_n\uparrow A$ i.e. $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots $ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ = A.

I want to prove that for $B_n=A-A_n$ we have that $B_n\downarrow\emptyset$.

**What I have is:**

$$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (A-A_{i})=(A-\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{1} A_{i})\bigcap (A-\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} A_{i}) \bigcap \cdots \bigcap (A-\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i})=\\(A-\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{1} A_{i})\bigcap (A-\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} A_{i}) \bigcap \cdots \bigcap \emptyset=\emptyset$$

Is this formally and **rigorously** correct? Am I allowed to use the dot notation like that and go to infinity in that manner?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is totally fine.  If there's a lack of rigor, it's trivial to fill in.

If we broke down the logic we could say 
$$x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(A - A_i) \iff x\in A   \ \wedge  \ \forall i, x \notin A_i  \iff x \in A \ \wedge  \ x \notin \bigcup_i^{\infty} A_i \iff x \in A \ \wedge \ x \notin A$$